# Is there a way to tell curl to not use cache

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to find out file size of an url:

```
$url1 = 'www.google.com';
$curl1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_exec($curl1);
$file_size = curl_getinfo($curl1, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD ); 
$file_size_kb = $file_size / 1000;
echo $file_size_kb;
```

The output is `43331`. I think its too low because i have google cached. Can this be true? Also i tested google on some other site that calculates size of url, and it was twice as big.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT` for this. From [`curl_setopt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> **CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT**     TRUE to force the use of a new connection instead of a cached one.

```
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
```

---

According to [RFC 7234 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) and [5.2. Cache-Control](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2)

> The "Cache-Control" header field is used to specify directives for
> caches along the request/response chain.

[5.2.1.  Request Cache-Control Directives](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1) defines several directives to control the use of caches for a response. One of these is

> **5.2.1.4.  no-cache**
>
> The "no-cache" request directive indicates that a cache MUST NOT use
> a stored response to satisfy the request without successful
> validation on the origin server.

So setting an appropriate header with

```
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cache-Control: no-cache"));
```

should ensure, that a valid and up to date response will be returned. I understand, that this may still result in a cached response, if the validation on the server allows to do so.

---

However, [5.2.2.1. must-revalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.1) is a [Response Cache-Control Directive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2) given by a server together with the response to a request

> [...]
> The must-revalidate directive ought to be used by servers if and only
> if failure to validate a request on the representation could result
> in incorrect operation, such as a silently unexecuted financial
> transaction.

Comment: Nope - this is not good enough to reject a cache hit. The server you are requesting info from, might still reply with `Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=600` (or similar), regardless of the *connection* towards the server is new or reused.

Comment: Nope - this will only create a new connection (which is just a performance hit) and you will still get the **cached** page back when server caching is configured. This is the correct way to avoid getting cached pages: `curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate")`

Answer (score 14):

The best way to avoid caching is applying the time or any other random element to the url, like this:
`$url .= '?ts=' . time();`

so for example instead of having
`http://example.com/content.php`
you would have
`http://example.com/content.php?ts=1212434353`

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Our website is behind a WAF.

Answer (score 13):

curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1); // don't use a cached version of the url

```
CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT TRUE to force use of a new connection instead of a cached one.
```

check example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#82300)

you can set header

```
$headers = array( 
                 "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
                ); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

this link may be helpful to you http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#96903

Comment: Thanks! 
Sending correct cache-control to the external server solved it for me. 
(Fresh connection did not help at all)

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cache-Control: no-cache")`

Answer (score 4):

Use **CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT** - TRUE to force the use of a new connection instead of a cached one.

**Example:**

```
<?php
    function check_url($url) {
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // get the header
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); // and *only* get the header
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // get the response as a string from curl_exec(), rather than echoing it
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1); // don't use a cached version of the url
        if (!curl_exec($c)) { return false; }

        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        return ($httpcode < 400);
    }
?>
```

for more details about curl check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

may this help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell `CURL` to use fresh data by setting `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT` to `TRUE`

You can read more about `CURL` function here :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php