# cURL error 3: <url> malformed - Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, curl, laravel-5.6, guzzle

While sending API post request, It's giving me a curl error, please have a look details below, and please suggest how can I resolve this issue.

```
cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-
errors.html)
```

## .env

```
APP_URL=http://acpapi.staging
```

## RegisterController

```
$user = $this->create($request->all());
            $http = new Client;
            // return $http->post(env('APP_URL'));
            $response = $http->post(env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID'),
                    'client_secret' => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_SECRET'),
                    'username' => $request->get('email'),
                    'password' => $request->get('password'),
                    'remember' => false,
                    'scope' => '',
                ],
            ]);
return $this->successResponse([
                'token_data' => json_decode($response->getBody()),
                'user' => [
                    'email' => $user->email
                ]
            ]);
```

## Error

```
"cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"
```

Comment: What's the value of the URL you're attempting? Are you 100% positive it's correct?

Comment: Try doing a `dd(env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token');` and verify you're getting what you're expecting.

Comment: it would be wise to not call `env` outside of config files ... use the value from the config system, `config('app.url')` ... if the config gets cached, the `.env` file does not get read and calls to `env` will return `null`   https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching

Comment: It's returning ```"/oauth/token"```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I mistakenly named my environment file as "env"

Make sure it is ".env"

Answer (score -1):

You could try clearing config cache with `php artisan config:clear`, if it was cached before and you changed the value this could be the reasson.

Also you could try [this](https://github.com/matthewbdaly/laravel-internal-requests) package for making internal requests.

Answer (score -1):

Not use

`php artisan config:cache`

You can reference here for further information : [Is there a way to tell curl to not use cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493769/is-there-a-way-to-tell-curl-to-not-use-cache)